# Class in Android like Struct in Swift

Tags: java, android

in my app in swift I have this code:

```
struct Question
{
    var QuestionLbl : String!
    var Answers : [String]!
    var Answer : Int!
}
```

After that I use this struct like this

```
var Questions = [Question]()

Questions =
            [Question(QuestionLbl: "Whats my name?", Answers: ["John","Josh","Adam","Leo"], Answer: 0),

                Question(QuestionLbl: "Whats my moms name?", Answers: ["Jessica","Crystal","Samanta","Kate"], Answer: 3),

                Question(QuestionLbl: "Whats my fathers name?", Answers: ["Ed","Blake","Jeff","Jonhson"], Answer: 2)]
```

Now, I'm trying to make the same app for Android..
So I created a class and tried to do the same thing like that..
This is the class file:

```
public class Question {
    String questionLabel;
    String[] answersOptions;
    Integer correctAnswer;

    public Question(String questionLabel, String[] answersOptions, Integer correctAnswer) {
        this.questionLabel = questionLabel;
        this.answersOptions = answersOptions;
        this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
    }

    public String getquestionLabel() {
        return questionLabel;
    }

    public String[] getanswersOptions() {
        return answersOptions;
    }

    public Integer getcorrectAnswer() {
        return correctAnswer;
    }
}
```

and this is how I try to do in main activity:

```
Question[] questions;
        questions = {
                 Question("Whats my name?",{"John","Josh","Adam","Leo"}, 1),
                 Question("Whats my mom's name?",{"Jessica","Crystal","Samanta","Kate"}, 1)
        };
```

But it didn't work.
Whats is the problem?

Comment: You need to use the `new` keyword.

Comment: You have to use the new keyword doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/declare-array-in-java) post for the syntax of declaring arrays. Essentially, it'd look something like:

```
questions = new Question[]{
    new Question("What's my name?", new String[]{"John","Josh","Adam","Leo"}, 1),
    new Question("What's my mom's name?", new String[]{"Jessica","Crystal","Samanta","Kate"}, 1)
    //etc..
}
```